# OnKey for one worksheet only

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to add code that makes the 'Enter' key(s) act like the 'Tab' key for one (protected) worksheet but not in any others. I have this code in the ThisWorkbook module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 Application.OnKey "~", "MoveThruForm"
 Application.OnKey "{enter}", "MoveThruForm"
End Sub
```

In a separate module I tried:

```
Private Sub MoveThruForm()
Select Case ActiveSheet.CodeName
    Case "Calculator"
    SendKeys "{tab}"
    Exit Sub

    Case "Lists"
    Application.OnKey "~" 'wanted this to set 'enter' key to be normal 'enter' key but it doesn't!
    'SendKeys "{down}" 'This works but is very much a workaround!

End Select
End Sub
```

This works fine in the 'Calculator' sheet but not in the 'Lists' sheet.

Any suggestions as to how I can get the 'Enter' key(s) to act 'normally' in the 'Lists' sheet?

(I'm using Excel 2013 and 2010.)

Comment: What if you just do nothing for the Lists tab?

Comment: Thanks for these comments - 'normal' for me means that 'enter' performs the default 'enter' function - i.e. moves down a cell or activates a highlighted button in an open dialog box (unlike tab). I tried just leaving out the Lists line - so just specified the Calculator tab but then nothing happens when you press 'enter' in the Lists worksheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - think I've worked it out!! Thanks for all the help.

Problem1: wanted the 'enter' key to act like the 'tab' key in one worksheet only so that it made the cursor jump to the next unprotected cell.

Problem2: wanted the enter key to work in the default excel way in the only other worksheet in the workbook.

Problem3: if another workbook were opened whilst the original (Test FRF3.xlsm) workbook was open, I wanted the enter key to perform the default excel actions in the new workbook. (Without the 'If ActiveWorkbook.Name =' bit, I found that the macro persisted if another workbook were opened whilst I had the original 'Test FRF3.xlsm' workbook open and if I subsequently closed the original workbook down with the new one open, then pressed the enter key, this reopened the original workbook! I'm sure that wouldn't go down well with users!!)

This seems to work:
In ThisWorkbook:

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()

If ActiveWorkbook.Name = "Test FRF3.xlsm" Then
    Sheets("Lists").Activate
    Sheets("Calculator").Activate
    ElseIf ActiveWorkbook.Name <> "Test FRF3.xlsm" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

    If Sh.Name = "Calculator" Then
        Application.OnKey "~", "MoveThruForm"
        Application.OnKey "{enter}", "MoveThruForm"
        'ElseIf Sh.Name = "Lists" Then
        ElseIf Sh.Name <> "Calculator" Then
        Application.OnKey "~"
        Application.OnKey "{enter}"
    Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

In separate module:

```
Private Sub MoveThruForm()
    If ActiveWorkbook.Name = "Test FRF3.xlsm" Then
        SendKeys "{tab}"
        ElseIf ActiveWorkbook.Name <> "Test FRF3.xlsm" Then
        Application.OnKey "~"
        Application.OnKey "{enter}"
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope that makes sense to people - happy to clarify if necessary!!

Addition: I found that this all works OK unless a user has another workbook open and starts to use another workbook with 'calculator' also open in the background. If they subsequently return to the 'calculator' sheet, Excel doesn't seem to 're-activate' the worksheet 'calculator' (so all keys go back to the default actions) so I added this within the worksheet as a workaround - it only works when a change is made (which is normally what happens when a user returns to the spreadsheet - they add some figures so it works OK as a workaround:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
'If Target.Address <> "$A$1" Then_or probably better even tho A1 is a protected cell:
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1:L100")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.OnKey "~", "MoveThruForm"
    Application.OnKey "{enter}", "MoveThruForm"
End If
```

End Sub

If anyone knows a better way of making sure the code runs whn the focus returns to the 'calculator' sheet, I'd be very interested.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need `OnKey` for this :) Excel let's you change the Enter key move direction.

[image]

You can change that via code as well.

In a module, type this

```
Public PreState As Long
```

Put this code in workbook code area

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    '~~> Store ENTER Key move behaviour
    PreState = Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    '~~> Check here which sheet is active and then
    '~~> decide where the ENTER key should move
    If Sh.Name = "Calculator" Then
        Application.MoveAfterReturn = True
        Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection = xlToRight
    Else
        Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection = PreState
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    '~~> Reset ENTER Key behaviour
    Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection = PreState
End Sub
```

Comment: I understand your hesitation but this is perfectly safe :)

Comment: Thanks for these comments as well - just to clarify my question (I can see I wasn't too clear - sorry!) I want 'enter' to move to the next unprotected cell in the worksheet 'calculator' (so not just move to the right or move down - i.e. mimic the 'tab' key) but in the 'lists' sheet, I'd like it to return to the default excel 'enter' action - move down a cell or confirm an 'OK', or 'Cancel' button (unlike 'tab') and also I'd like the enter key to return to the default action for all other workbooks. I'll try variations on this theme though ...

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I get any of this wrong, I'm learning as I go!

Application.OnKey changes the key's function at the application level, i.e. the change will affect every workbook that's currently open. So for it only to apply to one worksheet, the simplest solution I found is to set it when that worksheet is activated, and then change back to default when the worksheet is deactivated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate() ' in the worksheet that you want to change

    Application.OnKey "~", "YourMacroHere"
    Application.OnKey "{ENTER}", "YourMacroHere"

End Sub
```

and

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate() ' in the same worksheet

    Application.OnKey "~"
    Application.OnKey "{ENTER}"

End Sub
```

However the Worksheet_Deactivate event doesn't seem to trigger when switching workbooks, so to get around this, change Application.OnKey back to default in ThisWorkbook as well using the Workbook_Deactivate event.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()

    Application.OnKey "~"
    Application.OnKey "{ENTER}"

End Sub
```

Now that Application.OnKey is only changing when that specific worksheet and workbook are activated, you should be able to simplify the procedure it runs by taking out the If statements.

Hopefully this saves someone else time and frustration :-)